# Bamboo Deployment Projects - Can You Call Projects from Other Projects?

Tags: bamboo

I have inherited a collection of Bamboo build plans and corresponding deployment projects. Here is a particular example of how I would like to leverage reuse. We a four deployment projects (say ProjA, ProjB, ProjC, ProjD) that can be run individually/independently. However, we also have a project where we deploy them together (call it ProjABCD). Currently, ProjABCD replicates the steps from the individual A, B, C, D projects and executes them consecutively (e.g., if each has 10 steps, ProjABCD has 40 steps).

Is there a way to have a super-project (ProjABCD) that simply simply "calls" the four individual ProjA, ProjB, ProjC, ProjD? Ideally, this would also be able to roll-back to baseline state if any project in the group fails to deploy properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to come up with a scheme using the [triggers](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/triggers-for-deployment-environments-342098622.html) functionality.  There should not be a need to have a 40 step combined deployment (that breaks a lot of the value the deployments provide).  There are multiple ways to solve/simplify this problem.  For example you may choose to have two different builds, and only one of them triggers the 4 deployments.

Comment: hi Wesley. thanks for response. Yes i did realize that I could have triggers in builds to address this. However, I was hoping to have a way to do this just from deployment projects. There are times when we deploy without rebuilding. These are the situation where I want to occasionally run multiple deployments together independent of building the corresponding code.

Comment: @TimothyClotworthy I believe you can do most of that with a trigger and some creativity.  One solution may be to have an empty "build" that when manually executed simply kicks off the deployments.  Check out the Atlassian Labs Plugin After Deployment Trigger for some additional options - https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1216136/after-deployment-trigger-for-bamboo?hosting=server&tab=overview

Comment: thanks @Wesley. I think your last comment is the way to go. Just have different empty build projects with different triggers for different deployments. Thanks.